# Know what the following SQL code is doing

Tags: sql, sql-server

What does the following code do??

```
Declare  @StartDate datetime;       -- figure    
Declare  @EndDate datetime;         -- figure

Declare @CurrentDate datetime

Set @CurrentDate = @StartDate

While @CurrentDate <= @EndDate
Begin
    Insert Into dbo.Tbl_Time_Dimension 
    Values (@CurrentDate, 
            year(@CurrentDate),    
            datepart(Quarter, @CurrentDate),    
            month(@CurrentDate),
            datepart(week, @CurrentDate),       
            day(@CurrentDate))

    Select @CurrentDate = DateAdd(dd, 1, @CurrentDate)
End
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will iterate from @StartDate to @EndDate skipping by day and will insert a row into a table called Tbl_Time_Dimension.

The fields being saved into this table are : Date, Year, Quarter, Month, Week and Day for each date in the date range.

```
Declare @StartDate datetime; --figure
Declare @EndDate datetime; --figure

Declare @CurrentDate datetime 

-- Starts the iterator on @StartDate
Set @CurrentDate=@StartDate 

-- Iterates until @EndDate
While @CurrentDate<=@EndDate 
Begin 

    -- Saves data in table
    Insert Into dbo.Tbl_Time_Dimension 
    Values (@CurrentDate, year(@CurrentDate),
            datepart(Quarter,@CurrentDate),
            month(@CurrentDate), 
            datepart(week,@CurrentDate),
            day(@CurrentDate)) 

    -- Increments the date by 1 day
    Select @CurrentDate=DateAdd(dd,1,@CurrentDate) 
End
```

Answer (score 0):

this query gets two date
and for each **day** between startdate and enddate insert that date into Tbl_Time_Dimension as well as it's month , week , Day and quarter